# Importing and using a variable from another page React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Screen 1

```
export class Register extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          number1=0
        };
    
         render() {
        const {
          number1
        } = this.state;
    
        var NewNumber = number1 + 1; <---------
    
        return (
    
         <TextInput
                    onChangeText={(mynumber) => this.setState({ mynumber })}
                  />
```

Screen 2

```
export class Diet extends Component {
      render() {

          return (
 
               <Text>NewNumber</Text> <------------
```

Hey, I am trying to export the variable `NewNumber` from a page and importing it to use it on another page, I am using react-navigation, how could I do that?

Comment: did both of your screen in a same stack? or have you tried async storage?

Comment: Sounds like you actually want some global application state that can be shared and updated by various components around your app. Check [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or some global state management framework like [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/).

Comment: Yes, I am using React Redux and that's exactly what I'm trying to do, could you provide an example of how to do this, I am very new to programming

Comment: The official React-Redux docs are chock full of examples how to use Redux in a React project. Is there a specific issue you are having?

Comment: @PiersalvoMigliore You can check it out with demo application with codes. `https://github.com/Jebasuthan/React-form-registration`

Answer (score 0):

You can Import the first class and instantiate it to access it's properties like that:

```
 import {Register} from 'Path';

 var user = new Register();

 console.log(user.NewNumber);
```

Edit : If you want to share state between components i'de recommend using state management like Redux